# What are the differences between a TABLE and a VIEW in a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, view

I'm joining a number of tables and want to create some tables or views that are easier to query against to do quick analysis of our data.  What are the implications of creating a new table or new view with the combined data.

Currently the tables I'm joining are static, but this code may be moved to our live tables in the future.

Comment: Does the query that created the view have to re-execute every time you query against the view?

Comment: Do views update as your tables that the view was run on update?

Comment: Yes, updating the underlying tables will update the view "live".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a slight oversimplification, but a view is basically a saved query on a table returning a result (in rows and columns), which you can then query as if it were its own table.

As of MySQL 5.0, views weren't all that great because it executed the underlying query every time it was used, so there really wasn't much point to them (although they could be useful for code reuse). That may have changed since 5.0, though.

Comment: so if the query creating my view took 10 minutes to execute, queries on the view would take at least query_time_min + 10min (also an oversimplification)?

Comment: I believe so, unless it's changed since 5.0. Query caching and other internal "mysql is smart" mechanics may mitigate it a little (thus the oversimplification part), but...yeah, more or less.

Answer (score 0):

A Table stores the data

A View is a stored procedure like `select * from table` saved in the database for later use

you could have a view joining two tables and then select from that view without a join clause but get a joined result

Comment: so if the query creating my view took 10 minutes to execute, queries on the view would take at least query_time_min + 10min (this is likely an oversimplification)?

Comment: @T. Brian Jones - kinda - but the query for the view would take the same time to execute as executing the sql on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with views, as they don't necessarily use the indexes correctly in the underlying tables!

See this article for more information

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/08/12/mysql-view-as-performance-troublemaker/

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Rob's explanation:

You can grant privileges not only on tables, but also on views.  With this you can give access only to a compiled subset of a databases data.

Comment: @T. Brian Jones - If an answer provides useful information its nice to upvote it.